# Cause of dent on derailleur hanger?

Tags: repair, derailleur-hanger

I was cleaning my bike and when I take my rear wheel off I notice the quick release skewer is bent. I bent it back and when I lock my rear wheel back I notice the spin part of the skewer's plastic fell off.

When I remove it I notice that the derailleur hanger has a dent on it. I don't know what made that dent but I think I might have tighten the wheel too hard.

Right now I also want to buy a new hanger but I can't find it anywhere in the Internet, can someone please tell me what made my derailleur hanger to have a dent and what is the hanger's name.

Here is the picture of the hanger and thank you

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It kind of looks like the skewer end was too narrow, or perhaps the bent skewer made it slide to one side chew on the right side of the hole more than the left.  When everything is properly set up the skewer end should rest about equally on both sides of the hole.  And wear such as this can worsened by having the skewer too loose (or bent), such that it wobbles around too much.

Comment: As to the hanger's "name", it's a fairly generic unit.  Any reasonable bike shop should have a replacement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you describe worries me somewhat. Quick release skewers should not get bent. Normally they have no bending force on them because they are protected inside the wheel's axle, and do not take any load other then the tension holding the axle in the frame. Also, the cap should not be eating into the alloy derailleur hanger like that.

I suspect you have a cheap skewer with a smaller diameter metal threaded part in the end cap, with a larger plastic piece on top of it. The metal part has been pulled into and deformed the hanger. This may be a safety concern - the metal part may punch right through the hanger and make the  QR come loose.

This may have already happened to some degree and the axle shifting the the dropout bent the end of the QR shaft.

I'd replace the QR with a better quality one, with end caps that are completely metal. I'd also replace the hanger. Any bike store that sells the brand of bicycle you have will be able to help you. There are also some aftermarket vendors that sell replacement hangers for a wide range of bikes. Googling 'replacement bicycle derailleur hanger' will turn up at least one. You can then look up the make and model of your bike.

Answer (score 3):

A derailleur hanger is normally quite soft material, mostly aluminium. The rason for this is that a bang against the derailleur will make the hanger give rather than transmitting the force of the impact to the right-side stays. A bent or broken hanger is easier to replace than having to repair a distorted frame.

The nut on the quick release however is hardened steel with the purpose to 'bite' a bit into the dropouts. This is to assure that correctly tightened QRs hold the wheels firmly in place.

So this dent in your hanger is a normal consequence of the correct tightened of the rear QR. It's OK if the dent isn't too deep and the wheel sits properly. If it becomes too unsightly you may well replace the hanger. They are not expensive and it's a good idea to have one at hand when yours gets bent or breaks. Your bicycle dealer can provide them. You may also find charts on the Net from companies that produce hundreds of different types.

NOTE: Some frames have the hanger placed in a different manner, so that the nut of the QR doesn't eat into the hanger.

NOTE (bis): Bending back a bent QR isn't such a good idea. The thin shaft is hardened steel and bending may weaken it.